# Minifying so libraries linked by my native library

Tags: android, gradle, linker, minify, strip

I want to apologize for not creating right away a minimum reproducible example, I am trying to understand if I am missing some basic concepts on how minification works.
I have an Android application with its own gradle file. I have my own native library, built within gradle according to my CMakeLists recipe, which is minified all right (the library size goes down to 1/10, while the jni entry points and functionalities are all preserved). However, my library links to other so files (third party libraries) but none of these are minified so that the file size in /app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/ is the same as in /app/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/. How can I minify/strip native libraries to which my native library is linking?

Answer (score -1):

What if just minify code in library? Or compress files inside library? For compress files inside library need to paste archive format library in classes.dex.

What archive format compressing better? 7zip?

My answer, maybe it's possible...
For compressing android .so library, need to:

- minify code inside library.
- compress files to 7zip inside library (need to paste 7zip library in classes.dex).
- (another theme) set APK compressing level to maximal, for compressing size of library, and all files, or choose APK compressing only for library (another scheme, what maybe existencing).

My ideas working?

Comment: Minifying has litlle to do with compression, is about removing symbols/method/object code that is not reachable and therefore is not needed in the final application